# Facebook Card Game? Which architecture?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook, silverlight, playing-cards

I am developing a **Facebook Card Game** for my thesis and i am wondering which architecture fits best?

I am going to develop the game using Silverlight + ASP.NET.

On the one side the game should contain **player vs. player card games**.

On the other there will be also a lot of contant similar to Mafia Wars(or any other game like that) where you just interact with the **server** (incl. database)

I read a lot about ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight MVVM and that stuff.
But what **fits best** for a game like that?

Also i am not sure if i should go with Silverlight 4 already?

I don't want to start the wrong way.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: If this is your senior year and you haven't started your thesis by now, ouch! If it's your junior year, it's way too early to be thinking about this. I'd do some actual research by prototyping things first on different possible frameworks, then picking one based on what works best. When you're asked why you went with a particular framework, are you really going to say "because StackOverflow told me so"?

Comment: We have different deadlines in Germany ;-)

I am going to prototype anyway. But i am gonna start with what people recommend. If it already fits good i will go with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose a rich media architecture that you are familiar with. A card game can (and has) been done in just about every client + server architecture that exists.

However, here are some considerations:

- The Facebook platform has a rich developer history with PHP, not to mention a decently vetted API library in PHP5.
- Choose your rich media options carefully if you are concerned about platform support. Flash has a much deeper user install base than silverlight. If you are concerned about IPad support, go with HTML+CSS and use a good JS toolkit like JQuery.
- Any decent Facebook game that has a large amount of traffic will need an object caching strategy. Choose a server architecture that has one natively, supports one, or integrates with one (like memcached)